# Добавить элементы в scrollAreaWidgetContents

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты

Я работаю с *Qt Designer* и мне надо с помощью кода добавить в `scrollAreaWidgetContents` (созданный в `Qt Designer`) 88 кнопок, для каждой кнопки 60 `checkBox`.

Я мог бы вручную добавить в *Qt Designer*, но проблема в том, что мне нужно ещё обозначить имена кнопок (НЕ надпись на кнопке) от 1 до 88, и для каждого `checkBox` от 1 до 60. 
Если я начну это делать вручную, то потрачу ОЧЕНЬ МНОГО времени...

Как с помощью кода добавить эти все кнопки и `checkBox`-ы, если `scrollAreaWidgetContents` предварительно создать в *Qt Designer*?

`scrollAreaWidgetContents` я получил следующим образом:

```
scroll Area -> ПКМ -> Lay out -> Lay out in a Grid
```

мой код пока что выглядит таким образом:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QTableView, QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, 


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        uic.loadUi("pianinka.ui", self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

в файле `"pianinka.ui"` хранится: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1164</width>
    <height>901</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>160</x>
     <y>160</y>
     <width>641</width>
     <height>311</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="widgetResizable">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>639</width>
      <height>309</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
     <item row="0" column="0">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
       <property name="text">
        <string>PushButton</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="1" column="0">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
       <property name="text">
        <string>PushButton</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="1">
      <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox">
       <property name="text">
        <string>CheckBox</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="1" column="1">
      <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_2">
       <property name="text">
        <string>CheckBox</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, примерно так:

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


#class Example(QMainWindow):
# --------------------> vvvvvvv <------------------------------------------- # !!!
class Example(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        uic.loadUi("q1462164.ui", self)
        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.checkBoxs = []  
        for r in range(88):
            pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f"{r}")
            pushButton.clicked.connect(
                lambda ch, btn=pushButton, row=r: self.button_clicked(btn, row))
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(pushButton, r, 0)
            _checkBoxs = []
            for с in range(60):
                checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()           # f'{с+1}'
                checkBox.setObjectName(f'{с+1}')
                _checkBoxs.append(checkBox)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(checkBox, r, с+1)
            self.checkBoxs.append(_checkBoxs)
 
            self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
            self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)            
            self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['V1','V2','V3','V4','V5','V6']) 

            self.label.setStyleSheet("color: lightgreen; font: 34px;")        
            
    def button_clicked(self, btn, row):
        print(f'Вы кликнули кнопку `{btn.text()}` в строке: {row}')
        flag = True
        for checkBox in self.checkBoxs[row]:
            if checkBox.isChecked():
                print(f'checkBox `{checkBox.objectName()}` включен')
                flag = False
        if flag:
            print(f'В строке `{row}` нет отмесенных checkBox`ов')
         


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**q1462164.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>748</width>
    <height>552</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3">
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
     <item row="0" column="0">
      <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
       <property name="widgetResizable">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
       <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <width>359</width>
          <height>261</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout"/>
       </widget>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="1">
      <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
       <property name="frameShape">
        <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShadow">
        <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
       </property>
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
        <item>
         <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
          <property name="sizePolicy">
           <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
            <horstretch>0</horstretch>
            <verstretch>0</verstretch>
           </sizepolicy>
          </property>
          <property name="font">
           <font>
            <pointsize>14</pointsize>
           </font>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>Hello World</string>
          </property>
          <property name="alignment">
           <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="1" column="0" colspan="2">
      <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_2">
       <property name="frameShape">
        <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShadow">
        <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
       </property>
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
        <item>
         <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget"/>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо большое! это то, что мне и нужно было! я понял, что можно что-то изменять/добавлять в файл ui, и как это сделать).

Comment: @N0V1C40K пожалуйста. Я думаю что мои ответы для вас не только правильные, но и полезные для вас.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
       
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()                  
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)             
        
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)

        self.checkBoxs = []  
        for r in range(88):
            pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f"{r}")
            pushButton.clicked.connect(
                lambda ch, btn=pushButton, row=r: self.button_clicked(btn, row))
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(pushButton, r, 0)
            _checkBoxs = []
            for с in range(60):
                checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()           # f'{с+1}'
                checkBox.setObjectName(f'{с+1}')
                _checkBoxs.append(checkBox)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(checkBox, r, с+1)
            self.checkBoxs.append(_checkBoxs)
            
    def button_clicked(self, btn, row):
        print(f'Вы кликнули кнопку `{btn.text()}` в строке: {row}')
        flag = True
        for checkBox in self.checkBoxs[row]:
            if checkBox.isChecked():
                print(f'checkBox `{checkBox.objectName()}` включен')
                flag = False
        if flag:
            print(f'В строке `{row}` нет отмесенных checkBox`ов')
                

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(500, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо, но это немножко не то, что нужно. похоже, я плохо изложил свой вопрос. давайте так:
1) можно ли с помощью кода изменять что-то в файле, с расширением ui? <=> то есть в файле, созданного в Qt Designer? <=> то есть не создавать виджет, а добавлять в уже созданный Qt Desiner-ом ?
2) если можно, то как? мне нужно маленький пример, необязательно создавать как у меня 88 кнопок и очень много сheckBox-ов, достаточно чтобы в файле, созданном в Qt Designer был scrollAreaWidgetContents, и хотя бы 1 кнопка, добавленная в виджет с помощью кода!
P.S: если нельзя, то так и скажите....

Comment: @N0V1C40K чтобы получать быстрые и правильные ответы вы должны публиковать минимально-воспроизводимый пример и хорошо рассказывать что вы хотите сделать. Почему вы не опубликовали модуль `pianinka.ui` ? Опубликуйте его в теле вопросы.

Comment: а как добавить этот модуль? я что-то не нашёл как это сделать, поэтому и прикрепил скриншот.... на моём компьютере он хранится как файл с расширением ui

Comment: @N0V1C40K  точно так как и модуль `main.py`. Модуль  `main.py` и модель `pianinka.ui` - это обычные текстовые файлы.

Comment: если вам так нужен этот файл, то скажите, пожалуйста, куда нажимать, чтобы я смог его добавить в сообщение?

Comment: @N0V1C40K sorry, мне ничего не нужно. Вопрос задали вы, а значит нужно вам. Откройте модуль, выделите весь текст, сдвиньте все выделение табуляцией (на четыре пробела вправо), сохраните выделение в буфер обмена, нажмите кнопку править в вашем вопросе, в свободное место вставьте ваше сохранение из буфера обмена, сохраните ваш вопрос, все.

Comment: так можно ли что-то добавлять в файл, созданный в Qt Designer с помощью кода или нет? если можно, то как?

Comment: @N0V1C40K  я добавил новый ответ для вас, проверьте.